# bech32 serialized lightning invoice from lnd rest endpoint /v1/invoices

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, invoices, bolt11

I am using the LND Rest API to create an invoice. As response I get something like

```
{'r_hash': 'Wchr...E=', 
 'payment_request': 'lnbc210n1p....z9s', 
 'add_index': '4', 
 'payment_addr': 'Lyn...50='
}
```

According to LUD06 https://github.com/lnurl/luds/blob/luds/06.md I have to create a "bech32-serialized lightning invoice" from this.

Is the `payment_request` already bech32? Cause I can paste it in WoS and pay (think it's bolt11). Or how can I achieve that in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `payment_request` is a BOLT11 invoice, which uses Bech32 encoding.